# How to specify host name in pg_hba.conf file of postgresql?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3

We want to create a line like this :
host    all             all         vs1.nsdp.ir         md5
in pg_hba.conf file.
But it doesn't understand this host name. It's Ip is 192.168.1.60 and when we use ip address that's fine. But it won't work with host name.

Comment: Which Postgres version are you using? I using hostnames in pg_hba.conf is only supported since 9.1

Comment: thanks a lot,
we using 9.3,
by creating a reverse lookup in out dns server the problem is solved

Comment: Can you `ping` the hostname from the commandline on the Postgres server? Maybe the DNS resolution doesn't work properly on the computer where Postgres is installed.

Comment: @Obtice, could you post your answer and accept it?? please.!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We created a reverse dns lookup in our dns server so it can be able to reverse lookup the ip of our domain and the problem is solved