# Postgres can't listen to a specific IP address

Tags: postgresql

I'm trying to block access to my PostgreSQL and allow access only to Localhost and my machine external IP, something like: "172.211.xx.xx". This IP is provided by my ISP (Internet Service Provider).

In `postgresql.conf` I set the following line:

```
listen_addresses = '179.211.xx.xx'
```

But I can't connect to the database from my machine. I get "Server don't listen". If I change to:

```
 listen_addresses = '*'
```

everything works, but I can't do it. I need to enable access only to this IP. This is a security requirement of my project.

MY `pg_hba.conf`:

```
host    all             all             0.0.0.0/0            md5
```

Comment: Have you considered adding this IP at the `pg_hba.conf` file?

Comment: My pg_hba grant access to any IP, see i edited in post.

Comment: Just for testing (not the optimal solution) can you change the `md5` to `trust` and reload the config files using `SELECT pg_reload_conf();`? Leaving the `listen_address` as `*`

Comment: I tried it, restarted my postgres but didn't work.

Comment: if the pg_hba.conf is set `host    all             all             valid_ip            trust` and the `listen_address` is set `*` should actually let any user from this ip access any database on the server. What is the error message?

Comment: In pg_hba.conf i just configure to grant access to all IP's but in listen_address i restrict to only specific IP. Doing it, i grant that just my IP can connect in postgreSQL.

Comment: well, `listen_addresses` sort of controls which ips the server will answer on, not which ips the server will permit connections to authenticate. In my eyes, it's alright to set it to `*` and constrain the rest in the `pg_hba`, in other words: doing the fine tuning at the `pg_hba` is just fine.

Comment: So i made the change. My listen_address='*' and pg_hba: host    all             all             179.211.198.xxx/24      md5. But i putted a wrong IP to test and all IP's can connect in my database

Comment: try `host all all 179.211.198.0/24` and make sure the wrong ip is outside of this range :-)

Comment: I think that works, i got the following:  FATAL:  no pg_hba.conf entry for host "179.188.3.xx". Can i use a DNS name like "mydomain.ddns.net" instead of ip?

Comment: I honestly never used dns for that matter, but I believe it is possible. There are successful approaches using reverse dns lookups, but I am not familiar with the process: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22374768/how-to-specify-host-name-in-pg-hba-conf-file-of-postgresql . Would you mind if I answer the question with my last comment, so that other users can find it as well?

Comment: Yes, sure. Thanks Jim

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The parameter `listen_addresses` at `postgresql.conf` sort of controls which ip addresses the server will answer on, not which ones the server will permit connections to authenticate. In my eyes, it's alright to set the `listen_addresses` to `*` and constrain the rest in the `pg_hba.conf`. In other words: doing the fine tuning at the `pg_hba.conf` is just fine.

So ..

```
 listen_addresses = '*'
```

.. and ..

```
host all all 179.211.198.0/24
```

.. should do. Which means that all users have access to all databases from this IP range `179.211.198.1 - 179.211.198.254`

You can go further limiting access for specific users to certain databases:

```
host my_db my_user 179.211.198.0/24
```

Comment: BTW: it would make no sense to listen on an address that is not bound to an interface for the machine. Packets would never reach it.

Answer (score 5):

Had the same, `listen_addresses = '*'` was working but a particular IP was rejected. My mistake was that IP to use should be **NOT** the IP of the remote server trying to connect to PostgreSQL and not a public IP of PostgreSQL server but the IP of a network interface (duh). For example, on a PostgreSQL server run `ip a` or `ifconfig`

```
ip a
....
    inet XX.X.X.XXX ....
```

then in `postgresql.conf` use returned IP

`listen_addresses = 'XX.X.X.XXX,localhost'`

plus in `pg_hba.conf` IP of a remote server trying to connect to PostgreSQL. Let's say IP of a remote server trying to connect is YY.Y.YYY.Y

`host    my_db             my_psql_user      YY.Y.YYY.Y/32         md5`

Comment: why is necessary touch ``pg_hba.conf`` when ``postgresql.conf`` is saved with ``listen_addresses = M.Y.I.P,localhost,other.IP`` ???

Comment: Because apparently postgresql.conf specifies the internal ip address that the server uses to identify itself to other devices on the same net, and to translate the external ip to. And you specify the external ip that you want to have access to postgres in pg_hba.conf. Im theorising a bit here, but my experience was the same as @frmbelz. When I follow her suggestions and restarted postgres, https://www.yougetsignal.com/tools/open-ports/ recognized the port was open

Answer (score 2):

In addition to [Jim Jones' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49349393/111036), note that `listen_addresses` [can also take a list](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/runtime-config-connection.html#RUNTIME-CONFIG-CONNECTION-SETTINGS) of IP addresses and/or host names.

If you have several interfaces and/or several IP adresses, and don't want Postgres to listen on all of them (for example to only listen on a LAN interface, but not on the WAN interface), you can use something like this in `postgresql.conf`:

```
listen_addresses = 127.0.0.1,192.168.1.2,192.168.1.3,my_server.example.lan
```

Then, you still want to also configure `pg_hba.conf` and/or your firewall for control of the clients.

Answer (score 1):

#### `listen_addresses` are addresses local to the PostgreSQL server

The name of the `listen_addresses` setting in `postgresql.conf` may be misleading: It does **not** correspond to the remote addresses of client applications attempting to connect to the PostgreSQL server. Instead, you can think of the `listen_addresses` setting as the addresses that will be considered from the **local network interfaces** on the host running the PostgreSQL server for listening to incoming client requests.

If no `listen_addresses` setting is provided (e.g., commented out), it defaults to the loopback interface (i.e., `localhost`). Therefore, remote TCP connections to the PostgreSQL server won't be possible; only local connections through the loopback interface.

Note that you can set up filtering based on the remote addresses of the client applications in the `pg_hba.conf` file.