# Connect to postgis database in a local PC through an external Geoserver

Tags: postgis, geoserver

I have my geoserver installed in my machine (localhost). I create a database in PostGIS inside my geoserver and I create a web gis in leaflet that connects to that database. Everything works fine.

Now, I am using an external geoserver (in an external server). And I am trying to replicate the data in that external geoserver.

When I try to create a new source data as POSTGIS, it gives an error in the end. What can I do?
I change the host to my IP configuration and live the port as 5432.
[image]

Comment: Is the database also in an external server? Or you're trying to access your local postgresql from a remote geoserver?

Comment: The data is in my local postgresql. Maybe I need to install the PostGIS in the external server. Is that so?

Comment: No, it is not necessary to install the database in the geoserver host. You just need to make sure that the external database (in your case in your local computer) does accept external connections. You have to setup the `pg_hba.conf` and `postgresql.conf` files and make sure your firewall isn't in the way ;)

Comment: How can I setup tje pg_hba.conf and postgresql.conf files and how can I know if my firewall is not the way? Sorry for the questions but I never did it :)

Comment: can you tell me if this helps? https://stackoverflow.com/a/49349393/2275388

Comment: in a ubuntu system the files can be found at: `/etc/postgresql/12/main` (for postgres v12). Either `SELECT pg_reload_conf();` or a database restart is required. Let me know if it helps and I will formulate an answer.

Comment: I will try. But I have to give access to my computer right? What are the risks in the firewall? I never work with this.

Comment: this config I mentioned wasn't the firewall, but the postgres access config. Regarding your firewall, in case you do have one, you have to talk to your network admin. First try the postgres config and let's see what happens :)

Comment: Ok, I try. I configurate the files. I access to external geoserver and insert the host. But gives me this error: "Connection to 127.0.0.1:5432 refused. Check that the hostname and port are correct and that the postmaster is accepting TCP/IP connections"